# Azure DevOps Build Pipeline with two repos, different folders

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We're in the process of migrating some old projects and as initial step I have put our first project into a git repo. As an interim measure, we've also added the bin, packages and references folder to separate repo.

However the code won't build with the files in the bin folder etc, I need to be one folder up.

Locally we'd run a restore.ps1 script which will copy the bin folder etc into the main project.

So if we clone our binaries project in c:\binaries the project1 folder is created.
Inside that repo we have the follow structure.

```
c:\git\binaries\project1\bin\
c:\git\binaries\project1\packages\
c:\git\binaries\project1\references\
c:\git\binaries\project1\restore.ps1
```

In our code repo we clone the repo into the c:\git folder we get the project1 folder.

```
c:\git\project1\project1\project1.sln
c:\git\project1\project1\project1\bin\
c:\git\project1\project1\references\
c:\git\project1\project1\packages\
```

I've ran the simple generate pipeline in Azure Devops and it's created the following...

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

However, this is one folder too deep.

I've been looking at commands to pull in the binaries repo and run the restore.ps1.
But this won't work as I need to up one level.

```
- checkout: git://Binaries/project1@master

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'filePath'
    filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\test2.ps1
```

I know you can set working directories, but I think the whole build process is hindged around the location of the yml file etc.

Comment: Have you looked at the YAML documentation for how to perform a multi-repo checkout?

Comment: @DanielMann I have but that didn't mention folders... and the current repo where the pipeline exists is already checked out to the root folder.

Answer (score 1):

Yaml pipeline supports [checking out multiple repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops). So you can check out both two repos in same pipeline:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyGitHubRepo # The name used to reference this repository in the checkout step
    type: github   #For github git repo
    endpoint: xxx
    name: MyGitHubOrgOrUser/MyGitHubRepo
  - repository: MyAzureReposGitRepo
    endpoint: xxx
    type: git   #For azure devops git repo
    name: MyAzureReposGitRepo

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self         #check out the main repo
- checkout: MyGitHubRepo #check out the code repo
```

Then you can use a [CMD task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops) with xcopy command  or [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy the binary repo into main project folder. You even don't need to use the restore1.ps file.

And the path of the two repos, see [check out path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path).

Comment: Thanks Lance, yeah I saw the multi repo docs, however I haven't seen where I could specific a folder for checkout... Also I'd like to use the ps scripts so it's in sync with our local setup.

Comment: @JMWC2019 We can't specify a folder for checkout, you can check the last link (check out path) in my answer. It's by default will be checked out into different folders under same path. If repo1 is called RepoA and repo2 is called RepoB, then they'll be checked out to folder `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\RepoA` and  `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\RepoB`, same path but different folders. It's by design of check out option, and it's stated in document I shared above.